# Update multiple field values MongoDB by replacing values

Tags: mongodb

I am looking to update my object in MongoDB as follows

FROM

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(0, "vcbcbcbcvbdfsdgbbdvZNImOMQM6g=="), 
    "mypath" : "/sample/old/path/content/a/b", 
    "report_suite" : "mongo", 
    "target_s" : "/sample/old/path/content/c/d", 
    "topic_s" : "feed", 
    "id" : "/sample/old/path/content/retrieved/d4076995-f8a7-4b9f-912b-6f251a2fddcb", 
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1527875028199)
}
```

TO

```
{ 
    "_id" : BinData(0, "vcbcbcbcvbdfsdgbbdvZNImOMQM6g=="), 
    "mypath" : "/sample/new/path/content/a/b", 
    "report_suite" : "mongo", 
    "target_s" : "/sample/new/path/content/c/d", 
    "topic_s" : "feed", 
    "id" : "/sample/new/path/content/retrieved/d4076995-f8a7-4b9f-912b-6f251a2fddcb", 
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1527875028199)
}
```

Basically all field values that had paths /sample/old/path/content to sample/new/path/content

Please help regarding that.

I have tried

```
db.content.updateOne(
   { id:"/sample/old/path/content/retrieved/d4076995-f8a7-4b9f-912b-6f251a2fddcb" },
   {
     $set: { "target_s": "/sample/new/path/content/c/d" }
   }
)
```

but, I don't want to put "/sample/new/path/content/c/d" as value but just replace "/sample/old/path/content" with "/sample/new/path/content" and other remaining part as same

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify all the fields within the `$set` that you want to update:

```
db.content.updateOne(
   { id:"/sample/old/path/content/retrieved/d4076995-f8a7-4b9f-912b-6f251a2fddcb" },
   {
     $set: {
        "mypath": "new path",
        "target_s": "new path",
        "id": "new path",
      }
   }
)
```

Comment: yup thanks  I can add multiple fields using that, but how do I set a part of the new path. I have more that 10000 entries say, in that case I can use updateMany.But again, these paths contain unique ids hence it will be difficult to add unique values 10000 times.
What I look for is only ' replace "/sample/old/path/content" with "/sample/new/path/content" '. What comes before and after can be variable to each entry

Comment: There is no way to do this is MongoDB, you'll  have to iterate over each document and do an update on each one individually, you can checkout the update operators here - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-field/

Comment: @snaem you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771767/update-the-same-property-of-every-document-of-a-mongodb-collection-with-differen/50772179#50772179